# how to share a single shared library(*.so) instance between two applications

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I currently created a shared library(libshared.so), which contains a variable "a", which will 
    be modified by shared library api. i have two applications app1 and app2. app1 is using 
    shared library api, which changes the value of "a". now simultaneously when app2 is running 
    should see the changed value. 
    This is against the actual usage of shared library, as separate instance of shared 
    library will be created for every application.
    now i want to use a single instance of shared library between two app1 and app2, so that 
    they can see same code and data segment of shared library. 
    Is there any possible way to achieve this, by altering gcc linker flags

Comment: You are looking for [Shared Memory (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory#In_software)

Comment: Additional informations http://stackoverflow.com/a/19374253 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/14563172

Comment: No dvhh, i am not looking for shared memory, i have set of api's which will be used app1 and app2. how to achieve this using shared memory, if it is possible with shared memory

Comment: the shared object would provide a common api for the two library, but the memory space would be still private to the server

Comment: Yes you do. If you want to solve your problem, that is. Shared libraries only share code and sometimes immutable data. Not variables.

Comment: @anikhan Could you let me know your motivation doing this? I've trying Dependency Inversion recently, and placing a shared memory in shared library just came in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

These answer to :

- [What happens to global and static variables in a shared library when it is dynamically linked?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19374253)
- [C Linux: Global variable located in shared library as singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14563172/105104)

Would shatter your expectation from the shared library approach.

I recommend you take a look at [Shared Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory#In_software) and the [POSIX API](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sysshm.h.html) [shmget](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/shmget.html).

One process would act as a server and create the shared memory and provide the shared memory key to the client.

Another approach would be to create a pipe to share data between the process

You could read [this page](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html) to have more information about inter process communication on linux

Comment: The first link is not really relevant.